# How to read a string with spaces in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a user input string which must contain spaces.  Right now I'm using:

```
check = in.nextLine();

position = name.names.indexOf(check);
if (position != -1) {
  name.names.get(position);
} else {
  System.out.println("Name does not exist");
}
```

this just returns various errors.

Comment: And what are those errors?

Comment: Tip: don't ignore errors. They tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once a cause is *understood*, the solution speaks for itself :) If you don't *understand* them, update your question to include them so that we can explain them for you.

Comment: Are you reading from file or from console?

Comment: With your code, we don’t know what in is, what name is or what the errors are for your question. If you could update your question if it’s still open, or close it / mention when you solved it. What I understand you’re doing is not what the code does. So could you at least elaborate more on what you’re doing there? Are you trying to check for at least one space in the input string? Then you would have to check.indexOf(" "), and not what you’re doing with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question isn't very clear - specfically you like like you are checking that what the person has typed matches a known list, not that it does or doesn't have spaces in it, but taking you at your word:

1. Read the whole line in, then check using

a) Regex
b) indexof() - if your check is very simple

Possibly also want to do a length check on the input line as well (i.e all lines should be < 255 chars or something) , just to be paranoid

If you are doing more like what you code sample looks like then you do something like

```
ArrayList<String> KnownListOfNames = ..... 


if(!KnownListOfNames.Contains(UserEnteredString)){
    System.out.println("Name not found");
}
```

Typically you would also do some basic input validation first - google for "SQL injection" if you want to know more.